# OpenMP collapse gives wrong results

Tags: c++, openmp

I have an 3D array `z`, where every element has the value `1`.

Now I do:

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) shared(z)
for (int i=0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
        for (int k=0; k < SIZE; ++k) {
            for (int n=0; n < ITERATIONS-1; ++n) {
                z[i][j][k] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should add `ITERATIONS` to each element and it does. If I then change the `collapse(3)` to `collapse(4)` (because there are 4 for-loops) I don't get the right result.

Shouldn't I be able to collapse all four loops?

Comment: Multiple threads cannot access the same memory location without synchronization if at least one thread is a writer. You could try to add `#pragma omp atomic update` before updating `z[i][j][k]`. Anyway, it would be slow due to memory fences and cache contention. Much better is to use reduction as Gilles suggests.

Comment: Collapsing with the innermost loop included makes little sense in your case but adding `schedule(static,16)` should boost the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the 4th loop isn't parallelisable the same way the 3 first are. Just to convince yourself, look at it with only the last loop in mind. It would become:

```
int zz = z[i][j][k];
for (int n=0; n < ITERATIONS-1; ++n) {
    zz += 1;
}
z[i][j][k] = zz;
```

In order to parallelise it, you would need to add a `reduction(+:zz)` directive, right?
Well, same story for your `collapse(4)`. But adding `reduction(+:z)`, if all possible which I'm not sure, would raise some issues:

1. The `reduction` clause for arrays in C or C++ is only supported for OpenMP 4.5 onwards, and I don't know of any compiler supporting it at the moment (although I'm sure some do).
2. It would probably make the code much slower anyway, due to the complex mechanism of managing the reduction aspect.

So bottom line is: just stick to `collapse(3)` or less as you need, or parallelise you loop differently.

Comment: OpenMP 4.5 supports array reduction for C/C++?! I was not aware of that.

Comment: @Zboson [Semantics for reductions on C/C++ array sections were added and restrictions on the use of arrays and pointers in reductions were removed (see Section 2.15.3.6 on page 201)](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf#section.D.1)

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the heads up. This is one of the main things I've run into that I felt OpenMP truly still needed.